# After adding validations into Register.java file, data is not inserting into mysql database

Tags: android

## This is BackgroundWorker.java file

```
package com.example.lenovo.sampledatabasemysqlloginregister;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String ,Void,String> {

Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://192.168.0.6/login.php";
    String register_url = "http://192.168.0.6/reg.php";

    if(type.equals("login")){

        try {
            String email = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"ISO-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                   result += line;

            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return result;
         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    else  if(type.equals("register")){

        try {
            String user_name = params[1];
            String email = params[2];
            String contact = params[3];
            String password = params[4];
            String confirm_password = params[5];

            URL url = new URL(register_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
            +URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"
            +URLEncoder.encode("contact","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(contact,"UTF-8")+"&"
            +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8")+"&"

                    +URLEncoder.encode("confirm_password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(confirm_password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"ISO-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                result += line;

            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

This is my Register.java file

```
package com.example.lenovo.sampledatabasemysqlloginregister;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.AwesomeValidation;
import com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.ValidationStyle;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText username, contact,email,password,confirm_password;
Button signup;
AwesomeValidation awesomeValidation;
TextView clickon_signin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    username = findViewById(R.id.username_edittext);
    contact = findViewById(R.id.contact_edittext);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email_edittext);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password_edittext);
    confirm_password = findViewById(R.id.confirm_edittext);

    clickon_signin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.clickonsignin);

    signup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signupbutton);
    String regexPassword = "(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\\d])(?=.*[~`!@#\\$%\\^&\\*\\(\\)\\-_\\+=\\{\\}\\[\\]\\|\\;:\"<>,./\\?]).{8,}";
    awesomeValidation = new AwesomeValidation(ValidationStyle.BASIC);
    awesomeValidation.addValidation( Register.this,R.id.username_edittext,"[a-zA-Z\\\\s]+",R.string.name_err );
    awesomeValidation.addValidation( Register.this,R.id.email_edittext, Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS,R.string.email_err );
    awesomeValidation.addValidation( Register.this,R.id.contact_edittext,"^[7-9][0-9]{9}$",R.string.contact_err );
    awesomeValidation.addValidation( Register.this,R.id.password_edittext,regexPassword,R.string.pass_err );
    awesomeValidation.addValidation( Register.this,R.id.confirm_edittext,R.id.password_edittext,R.string.confirm_pass_err );


    signup.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (awesomeValidation.validate()){
                //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                String str_username = username.getText().toString();
                String str_contact = contact.getText().toString();
                String str_email = email.getText().toString();
                String str_password = password.getText().toString();
                String str_confirm_password = confirm_password.getText().toString();
                String type = "register";
                BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
                backgroundWorker.execute(type,str_username,str_email,str_contact,str_password,str_confirm_password);
            }

        }
    } );



    clickon_signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
        }
    });


}

public void backClick(){
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
}
public void onReg(View view){

}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986368/after-adding-validations-into-register-java-file-data-is-not-inserting-into-mys/50986510#50986510

Answer (score 0):

Please, apply this code to work your verification successfully

```
ValidEditText(editText,your regular expression,error_message );



 public static boolean ValidEditText(EditText et, String validation_tmp, String err)
    {
        String edtTextString=et.getText().toString().trim();
        if(!edtTextString.matches(validation_tmp))
        {
            Snackbar.make(et, err,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: can you please tell me where i have to add this code

Comment: set this method at where you use in which class and pass the value as follow method parameter

Comment: what you actual need in password field .i do something

Comment: i have done password field means i have used pattern for password. my question is when i add validations in my Register.java file then data is not inserting into my mysql database...... why???